# Postscript file - Image instead text

Tags: printing, driver, postscript

With a Postscript driver (Xerox, Canon, HP, all), when I create a PS file, for example when I print the test page in the printer properties, I get :

OK :

- The view of the result is correct (with GSview for example)

Not OK :

- The file size is to big, more than 4 MB.
- When I edit the file, I have one big image (doNimage). I think is the reason of the big size file.

The example file : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9bet657DEU5alV6WFZZdDFjMmc

I'm on Windows 10, similar problem with Windows server 2012 r2.

I let the configuration of the driver by default.

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks a lot.
Regards.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly is the question / the programming problem ? Ideas on **what** do you need?

Comment: Still nothing but guessing for us - do you think the file should be smaller? Why should it? Why should it contain text? What would you want to do if it did contain "text"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your problem, the file you posted a link to contains text. Here's an example:

```
360 4485 M <202530360E0F1102381030100D100B0824152D30103102020C302A1E19181B1E1730132E28301530132D3B02230B2A2E22081308>[46 16 28 70 18 42 44 44 54 32 28 32 36 32 25 39 65 40 40 28 32 44 44 44 18 28 53 45 20 47 38 45
40 28 34 40 40 28 40 28 34 40 18 44 44 25 53 40 16 39 34  0]xS
```

M is a moveto and xS uses the xshow operator to draw the glyphs represented by the character codes in the hexstring, using the values in the array to modify the width of each glyph.

If you were expecting to see ASCII character codes you are going to be sadly disappointed, the files uses an incrementally downloaded subset TrueType font, so the character codes are defined as they are encountered, that is the first glyph used will be given character code 1, the second will be character code 2 and so on.

Even without that, using ASCII would limit the languages that could be supported. Back in the 1980s that maybe didn't seem like a problem, but its a long time since that was considered acceptable.

If you were expecting to be able to modify the text by editing it in a text editor, forget it. PostScript is a programming language, and the output of a PostScript printer driver is a machine-generated program. Its a lengthy process for a skilled user of the language to decipher what the program is doing. The program is **not** amenable to alteration, if there's a fault in the output, correct the original document and recreate the PostScript program from the original.

PostScript is not an editable format.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your response. I see I was not very clear in my question.
Here is the state :

With the PS driver, on a windows server 2008, I get this file : 
http://expirebox.com/download/0bb511565377e8b74eead67641fe7f68.html
Inside the file I can see the text "Page de test d\222imprimante"

On a Windows server 2012 R2 : 
http://expirebox.com/download/60fa957cba97c82bbcd5c0e975825b52.html
I can't see any text. It's a printer page test too.

I need to see text because I'll print document with code inside. Code for a printer to identify page type. (for example a white page for the tray n° 1, yellow page for tray 2)

KenS : I understand your point.  But why the same driver give different file. 
I checked if it's really the same. The only difference I see is the OS, one x86, the other x64.

Thanks.
Regards.

Comment: This should be an edit to the question, not an answer. And I highly recommend CodePad or PasteBin for hosting large text files. The teaser links on that expirebox site are pretty horrific.